# R read data from stdout of system command into data frame

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, system, stdout

I call a system command with

```
driveFileList <- try(as.data.frame(system(paste0("/usr/local/bin/gdrive list "), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)))
```

I check the result with

```
print(dim(driveFileList))
print(typeof(driveFileList))
```

and I see that I have a list with 3 rows and 0 columns.

But the system command gives me actually something like this

```
1  Id             Name              Type              Created
2  23423423       nameOfFile1.csv   doc               2016-08-22 18:40:05
3  2342342        nameOfFile2.csv   doc               2016-08-22 18:39:39
4  34323334       nameOfFile3.csv   doc               2016-08-23 17:58:46
```

How can I 'explode' this, that I get a real data frame?

Thanks
Joerg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`as.data.frame()` doesn’t do what you think it does. The `system()` command gives you back a character string (of some format), so you need to parse it. Try `read.table()` or a similar function (which exactly to use, and what parameters, depends on the exact output of the call).

You either need to pass the text into the function via its `text` argument (i.e. `result = read.table(text = system_output, …)`) or you could use `pipe()` instead of `system()`, and read the resulting stream.

Looking at the [readme of gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive), it looks as if [`read.fwf()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.fwf.html) would be more appropriate than `read.table()` in your instance.

Comment: Thanks, the read.fwf did the trick!
So to read my files from gdrive I did 
con <- pipe("/usr/local/bin/drive list")
driveFileList <- read.fwf(
  file=con,
  skip=4,
  widths=c(52, 43, 18, 19))